# How to change tooltip background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a tooltip in my html file like this:

```
<span title="" class="duedate-warning-msg"></span>
```

And I set the CSS property like this:

```
.duedate-warning-msg{
     background: url("/static/img/error.png") no-repeat scroll 14px 12px white;
    border-color: #f5c7c7;
    padding: .5em 0.25em 0.5em 2.5em;
    title:"my tooltip";
    color: #D11006;
}

span:hover{
    position:relative;
}

span[title]:hover:after {
    content: "This statement is past due.";
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: "open_sansregular";
    background: #0679ca;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

The above style created tooltip perfectly. Only problem which I am facing is that I want background color of tooltip is blue. But it always shows gray. Why it is happening so?

Comment: You made it grey witht the background-image; Remove all lines that start with `background-image` and add: `background: #00F;`

Comment: Replace #eeee with blue color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `background-image` and add `background`, like so:

```
span[title]:hover:after {
    content: "This statement is past due.";
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: "open_sansregular";
    background: #0679ca;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    background: #00F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, in `background-image` property replace `#cccccc` with a color of your choice, assuming that you want to keep the fade-to-almost-white (#eeeeee) gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background image from `span[title]:hover:after`

Here is the working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bg4953y5/)